# Unity Facebook Login doesn't work on release mode on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, facebook-android-sdk

I made a game which can login with facebook. It works properly on debug mode.

I've published the game but facebook login doesn't work. Nothing happens when I click the login button.

I created release Key Hash, but Unity still has old hash

What should I do after that?

Comment: I asked the same question over a week ago. No answers or comments there either and I still haven't found the answer either. It seems this is a poorly documented topic

Comment: I solved @Immorality you can check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved!

I changed minify mode to "none" in the Publishing Settings at the Player Settings, it works properly

[image: Minify Error]

Comment: And what keyhash did you provide in the Facebook developer page? Or is it no longer needed?

Comment: You need keyhash, if you got an keyhash error, it shows correct keyhash

Comment: For anyone struggling with similar problems. I ended up updating Unity itself, regenerating the android manifest and i now got a different message stating a missing hashkey. Copy this hashkey into your facebook developer page. I had to type it over manually and needed to replace a l (L) with an I (i)

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this. this was a huge relief for me. I was juggling from weeks to sort this